# Instant crash when connecting a GIGABYTE RX 580 to a MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, gpu, kernel-panic

When I plug the eGPU into my MacBook, the computer reboots and then in the loading screen of macOS it will reboot again getting stuck in that loop. I thought I just had to plug in the eGPU and use it.

I'm using a MacBook Pro 2018 13" 4 Thunderbolt 3 ports, macOS 10.14.6 (Mojave).

[Crash Report](https://gist.github.com/zaloogarcia/26399849692e66109f9cf06bab807b3a):

```
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff80186daadd): Kernel trap at 0xffffff7f9cb62b0a, type 14=page fault, registers: …
```

Comment: Do these links help? https://egpu.io/forums/builds/2017-13-touchbar-macbook-pro-amd-rx580-tb3-gigabyte-gaming-box-macos-10-13-4/ and https://www.reddit.com/r/eGPU/comments/a17isr/my_experience_with_a_2018_15_macbook_pro_and/ ?

Comment: What version of macOS are you running? What sort of cable are you using?

Comment: MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2018, Four Thunderbolt 3 Ports)  Mojave 10.14.6

Comment: @GrahamMiln they didn't work :(

Comment: What cable are you using? Was one supplied with the eGPU? See https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-a-Thunderbolt-3-vs-USB-C-cable for how confusing cabling has become!

Comment: @GrahamMiln I'm using the usb-c thunderbolt 3 that the eGPU came with. I called support and they are useless

Comment: I would return the product as not working.

Comment: I will try with another macbook and see if it's the device or my computer

Comment: It's a problem with the T2 chip. Have you tried resetting the SMC?

Comment: Yes! I did, also I reinstalled macOS but no luck there. Seems that I have to return the GPU